# How to manage custom libraries in a similar way to VS solutions (where VS builds dependencies automatically)?

Tags: c++, linux, development-environment, dependency-management, clion

In Visual Studio a "solution" can have multiple projects, further a project can be a dependency of another project.

The reason why it is useful is because Visual Studio builds the dependencies when the project you are building is compiled.

This ensures that the dependency binary you are compiling with is always the most up to date version. Ignoring problems such as work in progress (and not release) code in the custom library, how can this behaviour be achieved in CLion or another Linux development setup/environment?

I understand that the normal workflow is to put the libraries into `/usr/lib/` however is there another approach?

Comment: CMake…………………………

Comment: CLion uses [CMake](https://cmake.org/) for project management. I suggest you reads [its documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doesn't CMake require you to have the dependencies already built and only link to the binaries?

Comment: For CLion the CMake system will generate makefiles that builds all sources and link with all dependencies. All you need to do is list the targets you have, list the source files for each target, and then list the dependencies for each target.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that this may seem trivial to a lot of people however could you please write an answer with an example using pseudo libraries `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` where for example project `A` is dependent on libraries `B` and `C`, and `C` is itself dependent on `D`. I understand the general direction however don't understand how to create that dependency graph using CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the structure you laid out in your comment, it could be something like this

```
project(A)

add_executable(A ${SOURCES_FOR_A})
target_link_libraries(A B C D)  # Make A depend on libraries B, C and D

add_library(B STATIC ${SOURCES_FOR_B})
add_library(C STATIC ${SOURCES_FOR_C})
add_library(D STATIC ${SOURCES_FOR_D})
```

Note that there is no special dependencies between C and D, since static libraries are often nothing more than simple archives of object files. Static libraries are not really linked themselves, you need to provide all static libraries when linking the executable, even if any of them is not used directly by the application.

If the libraries are *shared* then it's a little different:

```
project(A)

add_executable(A ${SOURCES_FOR_A})
target_link_libraries(A B C)  # Make A depend on libraries B and C

add_library(B SHARED ${SOURCES_FOR_B})

add_library(C SHARED ${SOURCES_FOR_C})
target_link_libraries(C D) # Make C depend on D

add_library(D SHARED ${SOURCES_FOR_D})
```

Shared libraries are *linked* and very similar to executable targets. Therefore the target `A` doesn't need to specify the indirect dependency on `D`, since it's linked into `C`.

<sub>[Note: The CMake commands shown above might not the exact syntax and arguments needed. Read [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/) for the exact syntax.]</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now!